# How to replace a searched String with lowercase by regex pattern in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have lots of DTOs which has

```
@Schema(example = "", description = "DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTIES")
private String property
```

I want to replace caps "DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTIES" into the lower case using eclipse search and replace. I have used
`, description?.*`
regex to search it, but how can replace the description text in eclipse search-replace(Description text is different for every property)?

Comment: You can use capture groups in the replacement, but there isn't anything to do  conversion to lower case

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this in Eclipse. This is something that the Emacs editor is very good at. Using that, I would get a grep listing of all the occurrences, record a keyboard macro to do the change at one occurrence, and repeat the keyboard macro 9999 times, and then save all the files that were changed. Bob's your uncle. It's not easy to get used to it, however.